# Convert C++ OpenCV code to Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I have a C/C++ OpenCV source code (which works fine) and I am rewritting it in Java using OpenCV (not JavaCV). I cannot find the correspoding Java class for CvBGCodeBookModel. 

I have searched thoroughly the OpenCV-Java site and many results from Google, I have also looked in many files in the OpenCV directory for any clues. 

The closest that I have found is class Algorithm 

(http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Algorithm.html    &

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Algorithm.html   ) 

but I cannot find how to use some methods e.g.:

 - cvBGCodeBookUpdate

 - cvBGCodeBookClearStale

 - cvBGCodeBookDiff

(The program was not initially written by me and I do not fully understand it but I have managed to add some functionality in the C/C++ version. If you need the source code inform me.)

Can anyone help me? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you did not find it, it probably was not yet ported to Java. Maybe you can use it with JNI.

Comment: I am not familiar with JNI and it would be too much for me right now to get familiar with it. Do you have to suggest something that would do about the same work? It is basically used to track motion, I have searched for tutorials (in java) but I have not found something good. Do you have any suggestions about that?

Comment: Can you describe what kind of motion or kind of video? Just track everything that moves or what?

Comment: From a camera feed which could capture people, cars, trucks. So just track everything. (Should I start a new topic?)

Comment: I think you can find some similar questions here. Otherwise start a new one.

Comment: Look for these topics: "BackgroundSubtractorMOG2"; "optical flow"; "lucas kanade (LK) optical flow"; "motion tracking". Its enough to give you dozens of questions for this topic.